# Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled (useEffect) Reactjs

Tags: input, react-hooks, user-input, controlled-component

```
export default function CitySearch() {
  const defaultCity = "London";
  const [city, setCity] = useState(defaultCity);
  const address = useSelector((state) => state?.cityDetails?.city);
  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    setCity(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleOnBlur = () => {
    if (city) setCity(city);
    else if (address) setCity(address);
    else setCity(defaultCity);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setCity((prevState) => address);
  }, [address]);
  return (
    <Box className={classes.root}>
      <TextField
        label="City"
        variant="outlined"
        value={city}
        onChange={handleOnChange}
        onBlur={handleOnBlur}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

The code works fine but throwing this error on console "Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component."

But the error goes off when i comment out the code inside useEffect

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the value of address by console.log(address).
If the value of address is null or undefined then this error will come.

Try this

```
useEffect(() => {
    setCity((prevState) => address??'');
  }, [address]);
```

This will set the state as empty string if the value of address is undefined or null.

Another alternative is to avoid setCity if address is undefined or null i.e.

```
useEffect(() => {
if(address) setCity((prevState) => address);
  }, [address]);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Check if any render sets a null or undefined value.